# How to resolve jsons.map is not a function error in Redis?

Tags: redis, redisjson

I have a simple array as such :

```
qux > [1,2,3]
```

upon deleting the `array` via `Client.json.arrPop('qux', '.' , 1)` I receive

```
F:\vite-multiple-chat\backendofmultiplchat\node_modules\.pnpm\@node-redis+json@1.0.1_@node-redis+client@1.0.1\node_modules\@node-redis\json\dist\commands\index.js:87
    return jsons.map(transformRedisJsonNullReply);
                 ^

TypeError: jsons.map is not a function
    at Object.transformRedisJsonNullArrayNullReply (F:\vite-multiple-chat\backendofmultiplchat\node_modules\.pnpm\@node-redis+json@1.0.1_@node-redis+client@1.0.1\node_modules\@node-redis\json\dist\commands\index.js:87:18)
    at transformCommandReply (F:\vite-multiple-chat\backendofmultiplchat\node_modules\.pnpm\@node-redis+client@1.0.1\node_modules\@node-redis\client\dist\lib\commander.js:100:20)
    at Commander.commandsExecutor (F:\vite-multiple-chat\backendofmultiplchat\node_modules\.pnpm\@node-redis+client@1.0.1\node_modules\@node-redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:160:54)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The element is popped successfully however the error is thrown anyway. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Which version of redis-server are you running? and which version of redisearch?